# Element has an invalid reference error while pushing the code using CCI command

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, push, selenium, cumulusci

I am trying to push the code using *cci flow run qa_org --org dev* command, But it is giving me **Element has an invalid reference error**

```
Running command: sfdx force:source:push -u test-xxxxxxxxxxxx@example.com 2020-01-01 17:02:41: PROJECT PATH ERROR 2020-01-01 17:02:41: 
2020-01-01 17:02:41: force-app/main/default/flows/Pull_Objective_Level_onto_Project_Objective.flow-meta.xml myRule_1_A1 (Update Records) - The element has an invalid reference to "myVariable_current.xxxx__Objective__r.Name". 
2020-01-01 17:02:41: force-app/main/default/aura/CreateUpdateActivity/CreateUpdateActivity.cmp Invalid type: xxxx__Activity__c
 2020-01-01 17:02:41: force-app/main/default/layouts/Budget__c-Budget Layout.layout-meta.xml In field: QuickAction - no QuickAction named xxxx__Budget__c.Download found 
2020-01-01 17:02:41: force-app/main/default/layouts/Submission__c-Response Layout.layout-meta.xml In field: QuickAction - no QuickAction named xxxx__Submission__c.Custom_Clone found 
2020-01-01 17:02:41: force-app/main/default/layouts/Submission__c-Template Layout.layout-meta.xml In field: QuickAction - no QuickAction named xxxx__Submission__c.Preview found 
2020-01-01 17:02:41: force-app/main/default/translations/pt_BR.translation-meta.xml In field: fullName - no FlowDefinition named Pull_Objective_Level_onto_Project_Objective found (1739:22) 
2020-01-01 17:02:44: Return code: 1 stderr: ERROR running force:source:push: Push failed.
2020-01-01 17:02:44: Exception in task dx_push Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/circleci/repo/cumulusci/core/flowrunner.py", line 223, in run_step task() File "/home/circleci/repo/cumulusci/core/tasks.py", line 140, in call self.result = self._run_task() File "/home/circleci/repo/cumulusci/tasks/command.py", line 76, in _run_task self._run_command(env) File "/home/circleci/repo/cumulusci/tasks/command.py", line 129, in _run_command return_code_handler(p.returncode, p.stderr) File "/home/circleci/repo/cumulusci/tasks/command.py", line 96, in _handle_returncode raise CommandException(message) cumulusci.core.exceptions.CommandException: Return code: 1 stderr: ERROR running force:source:push: Push failed.
Error: Return code: 1 stderr: ERROR running force:source:push: Push failed.
Exited with code exit status 1
```

Comment: Are you using a namespaced scratch org? Is xxxx your namespace or another one?

Comment: It worked after adding namespace in orgs/dev.json

Answer (score 0):

It worked after adding namespace in orgs/dev.json